# Radio/Checkbox styling using attribute selectors

Tags: css

I have the following css

```
input [type="checkbox"] {
    display:none;
}
```

Currently it styles all of the checkboxes. I would like it to style only the inputs with defined class="vote"

I tried :

```
.vote input [type="checkbox"] {
    display:none;
}

input.vote [type="checkbox"] {
    display:none;
}

input vote [type="checkbox"] {
    display:none;
}

input [type="checkbox" class="vote"] {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Umm. `[ ]` (space) is a descendant selector. `input[type=checkbox].vote` would work.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/947Aj/

Comment: I've edited my question, as the suggestions do not work.

Comment: For me, it does: http://jsfiddle.net/VWpnv/

Comment: Yup, the problem was on my side, had two identical pieces of code where I was having an if, so I wasn't meeting it .. ahh... you get me. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

instead of

```
.vote input [type="checkbox"] {
    display:none;
}
```

Write as

```
input[type="checkbox"].vote {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Well, you were faster. :-) +1

Comment: Double quotes around attribute values are only needed if there's a space, so `input[input=checkbox].vote` would also work fine.

Comment: @JaredFarrish So right, but its always safe to have ones, So I prefer

Comment: I honestly don't get the "belt and suspenders" approach. Is a space going to suddenly schlep in there? `</rant>` Anyhow, [`[type=checkbox].vote`](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/947Aj/1/) works too.

Comment: HAHA... i enjoyed `Is a space going to suddenly schlep in there?`. but its like having a good habit.. anyway. you are right

Answer (score 2):

Don't separate it with a space. It should be

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    display:none;
}
```

or

```
input[type="checkbox"].vote {
    display:none;
}
```